# How to get the values from all input elements inside a <tr> element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get all the input elements in one row in my form? 
For example, in the code snippet below, I have a checkbox and a text input box. I want to get the values of both these input types and display them to the user in the next td element containing the div id="hist" element.

```
   <tr><td>Head</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="headH" id="headH" ></td>
            <td><input class="NA" type="checkbox" name="headNA" id="headNA" value="N/A"></td>
            <td><div class="hist"></div><%=Utils.getMeasurementsCreateDiv1("Head","H",num) %>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Neck</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="neckH" id="neckH" ></td>
            <td><input class="NA" type="checkbox" name="neckNA" id="neckNA" value="N/A"></td>
            <td><div class="hist"></div><%=Utils.getMeasurementsCreateDiv1("Neck","H",num) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>UE</td>
            <td><input type="text"name="uEH" id="uEH"></td>
            <td><input class="NA" type="checkbox" name="ueNA" id="ueNA" value="N/A"></td>
            <td><div class="hist"></div><%=Utils.getMeasurementsCreateDiv1("UExt","H",num) %></td>
```

Also I have a 5 radio buttons and a text input box attached to it. These are all not on the same row but I want to get the value of the "pain1" element and the "cerCommentH" element and display it. Please note that the below is just a code snippet. I have several such elements in my form so I can't work with them individually using their "id".

```
   <tr>
            <td>Mech</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="pain1" value="Pain a">Pain a
                <input type="radio" name="pain1" value="Pain b">Pain b

            </td></tr>  
            <tr><td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="pain1" value="Pain c">Pain c  
                <input type="radio" name="pain1" value="Pain d">Pain d
                <input type="radio" name="pain1" style="display:none;" value="">
                <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.history.pain1l[4].checked = true;">
        </td>
        <td><div class="hist"></div><%=Utils.getMeasurementsCreateDiv1("Cehi","H",num) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="pain1" value="Other">Other
                <input type="text" name="cerCommentH" id="cerCommentH">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming perhaps you want to do something with each one:

```
$('tr:has(input)').each(function() {
   var row = this;
   var values = "";
   $('input', this).each(function() {
      values =  values + "," + $(this).val() 
   });
   values = "<div>(" + values.substring(1) + ")</div>";

   $('.hist', row).html(values); 
});
```

Comment: values will be a unreadable string? :) and values += $(this).val(); is shorter

Comment: You are correct,  however I have no idea what he wants to do with the values so I'll leave that up to the OP.  I do realize that `+=` is short however for readability I've done it the long way.

Comment: @lucuma I want to form a `<div>` with the values in the input field and display it back to the user. so something like (N/A-headcomment,Date). However, this code is inserting "undefined-13-Jun-2012" into all the `<div>`s, not just the corresponding ones to the input fields.

Comment: this is what I tried, with a little change to your code `$('tr').each(function() {
       var row = this;
       var values;
        $('input[type=text],textarea,input[type=radio]:checked,input[type=checkbox]:checked', this).each(function() {
           if ($(this).val()!=null && $(this).val()!="")
         values += $(this).val(); 
         });
       $('.hist', row).text(values+"-"+"<%=date%>"); `
   });`

Answer (score 0):

If you need it serialize() way then:

```
var result = '';
$('tr input').each(function(){
    result += $(this).attr('name')+'='+$(this).val()+'&'
})
//post result after all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//suppose trid is the id of the tr element
var all = $('#tr input');
//or if tr has no id, but table does have a id 'table1'
var tr = $('input', '#table1 tr:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize it into an array that can then be directly input into a jquery ajax method as data using serializeArray.

```
var rowIndex = 1; // row index to pull
// select all inputs that you desire to send, then use serializeArray();
var data = $("tr").eq(rowIndex).find("input").serializeArray();
$.post(url,data,onDoneHandler);
```